# Should I use JAI?

Tags: java, qt, jai

I would like develop program with a lot of image processing. I would like to use `Java`, and JAI, but it seems to me, that Jai is old and no longer evolve? (http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/)

I wonder, is it better choice to use `QT` and `c++`?

Two main pros which I am looking for is: cross platform code and good learning opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to do image processing, then what JAI did 3 years ago will be sufficient for the mathematical base of what you want to do now. New image formats etc would probably not require new updates to JAI.

I just can't think of anything that you'd need to add once you've got the basic operations - it's the application on top that's going to get new features.

Now how you get your graphical ideas into an `Image` that you can then process... awt, swing, Java FX...

Comment: ... if so, why in any browser I cant run that example (hello world) http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/javaai/jai/index.html ?;)

Comment: If you go to your system tray with the java icon, right-click and show java console, then you'll see that you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException` on `javax.media.jai.PlanarImage`.  It would seem that you need to drop the jai.jar into your jre/lib/ext folder for it to work

Comment: Yep! Worked for me - just install JAI on your computer and away you go.

Comment: Thx, +1, so is there any way to compile WITH that classs? It probably called "static compiling"? If user have to install it by itself, he probably give up.

Comment: You just bundle the jai jars as you would any other in your application. The installer merely upgrades a client JRE in so that you only installed it once.  This is better for applets, and was probably done pre-webstart as well. Speaking of web-start, you could also try https://jai-webstart.dev.java.net/examples.html, but I couldn't get those to download nicely on my connection...